# How to get user data after login in php with session

Tags: php, session, authentication, fetch

I am new at this php and session and trying to learn it.
I created a login system in php. I create a registration form so different users can register. **Now when they login I want to show the user data of who logs in at that time**.
 I am learning sessions in php so I don't know how to carry a logged in user data in to logged in area.

Simply I don't know how to get login user data through sessions in php.

THIS IS LOGIN.PHP:

```
<?php


    error_reporting(0);
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('could not connect to database');

    mysql_select_db('addscloud');

    @session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  tbl_reg where reg_mobile = '".$_POST['reg_mobile']."' and reg_pass = '".$_POST['reg_pass']."' ";

    var_dump($query);

    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);


    if($row)
    {
    $_SESSION['var']=2; 
    header('Location:registration_user.php');
    }

    else
    {
    $_SESSION['msg']="invalid user Name or Password";
    header('Location:login_form.php');
    }

    }


    ?>

 <?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
 {
 echo $_SESSION['msg'];
  unset($_SESSION['msg']);
  }
  ?>
```

AND THE LOG AFTER SUCCESSFUL LOGIN:

```
<?php
    @session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['var']))
    {
    }
    else
    {
    header('location:login_form.php');
    }



    ?>

    <?php 

    if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);

    }


    ?>
```

Comment: There is nothing in your brackets for the condition `if (isset($_SESSION['var'])) { ... }`

Comment: actually i done this example after watching a tutorial online i am learning this login system for different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On successful validation of the user, put all the necessary user details into a session.
For example at login.php,

$_SESSION['user'] = $row;

so you can get the necessary user details anywhere at site.

Hope this helps to you.. ;)